# How to define the Spring Integration errorChannel?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

In a previous spring integration application, I was able to **subscribe** to the application `errorChannel` and my failed messages, sent out-bound, would end up in my (pre-defined) handler.

However, now I am attempting to implement the same pattern, in a larger application, that has a *pre-existing in-bound* setup and I am no longer able to be pick up on the errorChannel.

Most alarming to me, is a reference to:

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="errorChannel" task-executor="errorChannelExecutor"/>
```

When I start up this application, with my inclusion, I no longer see the following reassuring messages:

```
No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
Adding {logging-channel-adapter:o.s.i.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
Channel'o.s.c.s.C.errorChannel' has 2 subscriber(s).
```

1. Do you think that the `int:publish-subscribe-channel` is *overriding*
   my access to the application errorChannel?
2. Why does it no longer reference the default errorChannel in the log?
3. Is there a way that I can define an *alternate* error channel that is solely concerned with out-bound connections?

Comment: Yes, it is overriding the default `errorChannel` with a pub-sub channel.  Rename the pub-sub and you should be good. Wanna try that?

Comment: The thing is that the `errorChannel` is *already* defined so I cannot simply rename it in spring integration. Unless there is a way that I can use a *different* name for the error channel, specifically in my out-bound portion of the application?

Comment: I meant renaming your pub-sub channel (the one in your question is the one you defined, right?) - not renaming the default errorChannel.

Comment: Thanks for replying - the pub-sub channel is pre-existing in-bound code. I would normally subscribe to the default channel for my out-bound section. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using async task executors, exceptions caught by the executor are sent to a channel called `errorChannel` by default.

If you define such a channel, it overrides the default which would otherwise be created by the framework (and the logging adapter that is subscribed to it, is not subscribed; you have to do that if you define your own channel).

For inbound channel adapters/gateways that are message-driven (e.g. http, amqp etc), where do don't have a downstream async executor, you have to explicitly set the `error-channel` property if you want exceptions to go there.

Comment: So it is called the `errorChannel` by **default**, but there is a way to use a different name? We are using Kafka, specifically a `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` for our out-bound message flow. Can we simply _rename_ the errorChannel there?

Comment: No; the error channel goes on whatever starts the flow (e.g. gateway, inbound channel adapter); the outbound exception is caught and the `ErrorMessage` sent to the error channel. Or you can add an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlingAdvice` to the outbound adapter, but for the most part, downstream problems are handled on inbound endpoints.

Comment: Could you please point me at an example or some documentation for the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlingAdvice`? I take it that if I use this technique, I will be able to keep the in-bound and out-bound error handling completely separate.

Comment: The [retry-and-more sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more#expression-evaluating-advice-demo) has an example when using XML configuration. If you are using Java configuration, the `adviceChain` is on the `@ServiceActivator`; if using the Java DSL, the advice is on the endpoint spec. The `ErrorMessage` sent to the failure channel has an exception payload with the failed message, the cause, and the result of evaluating the expression.

Comment: Actually I had a quick look at the code, but I didn't see any reference to an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlingAdvice`. Are you sure you have the right example file?

Comment: See the XML config in src/main/resources https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/intermediate/retry-and-more/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/expression-advice-context.xml